# MATLAB surf meshgrid issue - 2 vectors 1 matrix - surface plot

Tags: matlab, plot, mesh

I have 2 vectors and one matrix and I would like to make a surface plot.

1. first vector A , the distance vector A=1:1:100 (size 1 100);
2. second vector B, the time vector B=1:1:10 (size 10);
3. matrix C, every column has the data for each value of B (size 100 10)

How could I use the meshgrid and/or the surf function for getting a surface 3D plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[AA, BB] = ndgrid(A,B);
surf(BB,AA,C)
```

Or use the version of [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) that allows two vectors as its two first inputs:

```
surf(B,A,C)
```

which for your particular vectors (`[1 2 ...]`) could be simplified to the single-input version

```
surf(C)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! works fine! if you know also how to fill with color or projection the side walls will be perfect!

Comment: ALSo, in my program, after the 10th value of B, B as C increase their size (B size 11, 12, 13 .. and C size 100 11, 100 12, 100 13 ... ). Please, is possible to use the same function ndgrid for having a surface plot after the 10th value? and how ?

Comment: @user1640255 As for color projection: I don't know how; and it wasn't in the original question. For the increased size, can't you use the same approach?

Comment: I will try. My program has 2 parts. The first part is until the time vector take value 10. Afterwards the A and C increase their size together. So, for B=1:1:12 (size 12), I have  A=1:1:102 (size 1 102)  and C (size 102 12). IS little tricky...

Comment: Sorry, I have confused. The size is the same. What happen is that the C is filled only in 50% of the 100 values, rest filled with zero. After the the 10th time vector value, the C goes to 55%, 60% etc. SO, A=1:1:100 (size 1 100) 2. B=1:1:12 (size 12) 3. matrix C,  (size 100 12). I am confused now.

Comment: itd ok... i DONE IT. THANKS for you help